# How to distribute PHP code within HTML elements in segments

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Consider the following code which works fine.

```
<?php 
require_once 'php/db_conx.php';
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY lastupdated") or die  (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
{ ?>

            <input name="1" type="submit"  value=" ">
<span><?php echo $row['name'];?></span>
<?php 
// then i close the PHP started at on top.

}?>
```

Now, the following won't print anything on print_r but just 'array()' not the session      $Variable '$U' itself.

```
<?php
    {
    session_start(); 
$_SESSION['U'] = 'www.gmail.com';    
?>
```

Some HTML

```
<?php 
 Print_r ($_SESSION);
 }
?>
```

Comment: `session_start();`  should be called before sending even direct HTML to browser

Comment: Session start has been called, read again on the code i have a problem with not the one i say is working.

Comment: Am not clear to understand about your question.

Comment: But you have `HTML` being output even before that, that's the problem

Comment: @BlessingThinker Put session_start() to the beginning of the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works fine:

```
<?php

session_start(); 
$_SESSION['U'] = 'www.gmail.com';    
?>

<p>Hello</p>

<?php 
   Print_r ($_SESSION);
?>
```

and prints

Hello

Array ( [U] => www.gmail.com )

Answer (score 0):

Put `session_start()` Beginning of the page

Check this example

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['views']=1;
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
//retrieve session data
echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
?>

</body>
</html>
```